# Jenkins/ API how to read build info https

Tags: api, jenkins

I want to be able retrieve json from jenkins api like:
  jenkinsurl/job/nameofmyjob/lastBuild/api/json

But my jenkins is running on https and using matrix-based security.

Any ideas?

Comment: Error :unable to connect.  As Jenkins deny unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

My Jenkins server is connected to a LDAP user directory and I'm able to trigger a job with this URL:

```
curl -X POST -u MY_USER:MY_PASSWORD https://my.jenkins.instance.com/job/MY_JOB/build
```

If you have a build user, I think you can also use the API Token to manage the authentication.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I've already tried to send app token in a URL. But it didn't work.